# compilation error in maven but not in eclipse for self types

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, covariance, self-type

I'm trying to create some [java SELF types](https://www.sitepoint.com/self-types-with-javas-generics/)

What is the reason for which

1. everything compiles perfectly in eclipse
2. maven compiles with the following error

   **types Foo and FooLike are incompatible; both define existing(), but with unrelated return types**

## Details

Maven&Java version:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: D:\home\raiser-apps\apps\maven\current\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: D:\home\raiser-apps\apps\adopt8-hotspot\current\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Eclipse version:

```
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) - Build id: 20190917-1200
```

## The test

This compiles in eclipse but not in maven.

The interface Foo and Bar are part of the public API, FooLike is an internal.

```
package org.jedio;

import java.util.List;

public class CompilationBugTest {
  public interface Foo {
    <T extends Foo> List<T> existing();
  }

  public interface FooLike<SELF extends FooLike<SELF>> extends Foo {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // eclipse warning:
    // Type safety: The return type List<SELF> for existing() from the type CompilationBugTest.FooLike<SELF> needs
    // unchecked conversion to conform to List<CompilationBugTest.Foo> from the type CompilationBugTest.Foo
    @Override
    default List<SELF> existing() {
      throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented yet!!!");
    }
  }

  /**
   * - eclipse - Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) - Build id: 20190917-1200
   *   - no warning or error
   * - maven - using default 1.8 compiler, maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1
   *   - error:types Foo and FooLike<Bar> are incompatible; both define existing(), but with unrelated return types
   */
  public interface Bar extends FooLike<Bar>, Foo {
  }
}
```

---

## Update

Adding the following implementation to Bar will allow compilation in maven as well

```
@Override
default List<Bar> existing() {
  return FooLike.super.existing();
}
```

Comment: The interface `FooLike` defines two methods: `List<SELF> existing()` and `<T extends Foo> List<T> existing()`. They both have the same erasure, but are not equal.

Comment: Yes they are a little different. There are multiple things combined that don't know how to manage anymore: erasure, covariance, metod signature where the returned type doesn't count, diamond inheritance. Somehow I managed to explain these to eclipse compiler, while maven/adopt-openjdk compiler complains.